Contact Form 7: invalid JSON response 404 not found on submit
My wordpress is fully up to date and all plugins are up to date
When click the submit button of Contact Form 7 I get the following errors. The form is sent and submitted but  get no success notification and the spinner is spinning indefinitely.
console:
[Error] {code: "invalid_json", message: "The response is not a valid JSON response."}
    error

and if I look at xhr request I see in response for an empty form the following error but spinner is spinning and nothing displays
404: Not Found{"contact_form_id":82,"status":"validation_failed","message":"One or more fields have an error. Please check and try again.","invalid_fields":[{"field":"birth","message":"Please fill out this field.","idref":null,"error_id":"wpcf7-f82-p13-o1-ve-birth"},{"field":"fullname","message":"Please fill out this field.","idref":null,"error_id":"wpcf7-f82-p13-o1-ve-fullname"},{"field":"city","message":"Please fill out this field.","idref":null,"error_id":"wpcf7-f82-p13-o1-ve-city"},{"field":"height","message":"Please fill out this field.","idref":null,"error_id":"wpcf7-f82-p13-o1-ve-height"},{"field":"shoe","message":"Please fill out this field.","idref":null,"error_id":"wpcf7-f82-p13-o1-ve-shoe"},{"field":"email","message":"Please fill out this field.","idref":null,"error_id":"wpcf7-f82-p13-o1-ve-email"}],"posted_data_hash":"","into":"#wpcf7-f82-p13-o1"}


I'd ask this on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

@stdunbar I did and they closed my question as off topic saying that stack overflow is the suited place

How is this question on topic here? It's not about programming, it's about debugging an error in form submission.

@HowardE what can I say; the thoughts police you know...
